# Bash script not adding variables to session

Tags: command-line, 14.04, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I have a bash script that I have added as a startup application. It does a bunch of exports and alias assignment.

```
#! /bin/bash

alias devhm='cd ${DEV_HOME}; ll';
alias wlhm='cd ${WL_HOME}; ll';
alias dirch='watch --interval=1 "ls -la"';
alias vols='watch --interval=1 "df -h"';
alias svn-update='svn update --depth infinity ./*';
alias mci="~/mci.sh";
alias vncserver="vncserver -geometry 1680x1050";
alias ..="cd ..";
alias hist="history | grep ";

export PROXY_HOST=proxy.my.setup;
export PROXY_PORT=3128;

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib;
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64;
export TNS_ADMIN=${ORACLE_HOME}/network/admin;

echo "DONE!";
```

But none of these values are available in my terminal sessions anymore. Even when I run the script straight into the terminal like so:

```
./setup.sh
```

I see the "DONE!" prompt printed but no aliases or env variables are set.

If I copy and paste the contents of the file into the terminal the aliases and env variables are set.

I have tried adding a line to execute the script from `.bashrc` also but still no aliases or env variables set.

Any ideas what might be going on here? Also could anyone suggest a better way to have these env variables/aliases added to every terminal session?

Comment: How are you trying to execute the file in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: By adding `./setup.sh` to the end of the file.

Comment: Partially yes but it doesn't cover what I need to do to run it was a startup process and apply it to all terminal sessions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.bashrc` reference your custom startup script using `. setup.sh` instead of `./setup.sh`. That will cause it to be executed in the context of the current session instead of being executed as a separate program with its own context.

Comment: Beautiful!! So if I want this to run as startup application can I just type `. setup.sh` in to the command window?

Comment: You can, or you can just add it to your `.bashrc` after whatever else is in there.

Comment: awesome could you specify that in your answer coz they're trying to peg this as a duplicate :)